# Unclear limit in showing that $\ell^2$ spaces are complete

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm working my way through the book [Introduction to Hilbert Spaces with Applications](https://www.elsevier.com/books/introduction-to-hilbert-spaces-with-applications/debnath/978-0-08-045592-1) and trying to follow the early example (1.4.6) showing that $\ell ^2$ spaces are complete (Cauchy sequences $(a_n) \in \ell ^2$ have their converge in $\ell ^2$). At this point only basic results of normed vector spaces are shown, neither the Dominated nor Monotone convergence theorems are presented.

They start by declaring the Cauchy sequence $(a_n) \in \ell ^2$ with elements $a_n = (\alpha_{n1}, \alpha_{n2}, ...)$. By the definition of Cauchy sequences and the $\ell ^2$ norm they get that there exists $N$ such that

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{mk} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 < \epsilon^2 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

for $m, n > N$. They conclude that this means that for each $k$, $|\alpha_{mk} - \alpha_{nk}| < \epsilon$ so $(\alpha_{nk})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore converges to a limit $\alpha_k \in \mathbb{C}$. **Now to the part that is unclear to me**. They state that from (1), by letting $m \rightarrow \infty$, we get

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{k} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 \le \epsilon^2 \tag{2}
\end{equation}

for $n > N$, without mentioning how. It seems like this limit is supposed to be obvious, but the only methods I can figure out or find rely on being able to state that ($\stackrel{!}{=}$)

\begin{equation}
\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{k} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 = \lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{K}|\alpha_{k} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 \stackrel{!}{=} \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}|\alpha_{mk} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{k} - \alpha_{nk}|^2
\end{equation}

using later results like the aforementioned convergence theorems. Is there some better method I'm completely missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it in a few steps. Take any constant $n>N$ and $K\in\mathbb{N}$. For all $m>N$ we have:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^K |\alpha_{mk}-\alpha_{nk}|^2\leq\epsilon^2
$$

Now, this is a finite sum so there is no problem to use arithmetic of limits. By taking $m\to\infty$ we get the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^K |\alpha_k-\alpha_{nk}|^2\leq\epsilon^2$. And since this is true for all $K\in\mathbb{N}$ (since $K$ was an arbitrary natural number), by taking $K\to\infty$ we get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_k-\alpha_{nk}|^2\leq\epsilon^2$.

By the way, it is important to write non strict inequalities. After all, strict inequalities are not always preserved when taking a limit.

Comment: Thanks Mark, really appreciate the answer!

To make sure I follow you: you're saying that instead of directly trying to evaluate the limit of the sum as $m \rightarrow \infty$, realize that the inequality holds for partial sums from $1$ to $K$ and take each limit in the desired order from there?

I.e. this argument doesn't also show that $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{K}|\alpha_{k} - \alpha_{nk}|^2 = \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{K}\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty}|\alpha_{mk} - \alpha_{nk}|^2$?

Comment: My answer doesn't really prove that you can interchange between a limit and an infinite sum. I didn't really focus on that in the answer, because our goal was just to achieve the inequality $\sum_{k=1}^\infty |\alpha_k-\alpha_{nk}|^2\leq\epsilon^2$. So instead of doing it directly we prove that we have $\sum_{k=1}^K |\alpha_k-\alpha_{nk}|^2\leq\epsilon^2$ for every $K\in\mathbb{N}$. This is easier, because interchanging between a limit and a finite sum is something we clearly know we are allowed to do. And this implies the required inequality.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks again. Maybe this is what the authors meant even though the wording made me think they just applied the limit to the existing inequality.

Answer (score 1):

It may be convenient to consider elements of $\ell_2$ as functions $X:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ such that $\|X\|^2_2:=\sum_{k\geq1}|X(k)|^2<\infty$.

Suppose $\{X_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. To see that there is $X\in \ell_2$ such that $\|X-X_n\|_2\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, one may proceed as follows:

1. Show first that $X_n$ convergent point wise, that is, for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n(k)=: X(k)$ exists. Then $X$ will be our candidate for a limit in $\ll_2$. Pointwise convergence will follow from the simple observation that
   $$|X_n(k)-X_m(k)|\leq \|X_n-X_m\|_2$$
   for each $k$, and $n,m$. For $\{X_n\}$ being a Cauchy sequence in $\ell_2$ implies that $\{X_n(k):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $k$.
2. Now that the point wise limit is established, let show that $X\in \ell_2$. There exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m\geq N$,
   $$\|X_n-X_m\|_2\leq1$$
   Then for any $K$
   $$
   \sum^K_{k=1}|X_n(k)|^2\leq \|X_n\|^2_2\leq (\|X_n-X_N\|_2+\|X_N\|_2)^2\leq 2(1+\|X_N\|^2_2)$$

Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ shows that
$$
\sum^K_{k=1}|X(k)|^2\leq 2(1+\|X_N\|^2_2)
$$
for all $K$. Therefore $\|X\|^2_2=\lim_{K\rightarrow\infty}\sum^{K}_{k=1}|X(k)|^2<\infty$.

3. Show that $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $\ell_2$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\{X_n\}$ is Cauchy,
   there exists $N_\varepsilon$ such that
   $$
   \|X_n-X_m\|_2<\varepsilon\quad\text{for all}\quad n,m\geq N_\varepsilon
   $$
   Since $X\in\ell_2$, there exits $K_\varepsilon$ such that
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \sum_{k>K_\varepsilon}|X(k)|^2&<\varepsilon^2\\
   \sum_{k>K_\varepsilon}|X_N(k)|^2&<\varepsilon^2
   \end{align}
   $$

$$
\begin{align}
\|X-X_n\|_2&\leq \|X-X_N\|_2+\|X_N-X_n\|_2\\
&< \Big(\sum^{K_\varepsilon}_{k=1}|X(k)-X_N(k)|^2\Big)^{1/2} + \Big(\sum_{k>K_\varepsilon}|X(k)|^2+|X_N(k)|^2\Big)^{1/2} + \varepsilon\\
&< \Big(\sum^{K_\varepsilon}_{k=1}|X(k)-X_N(k)|^2\Big)^{1/2} + 3\varepsilon\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(\sum^{K_\varepsilon}_{k=1}|X_n(k)-X_N(k)|^2\Big)^{1/2} +3\varepsilon\leq 4\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$
since the limit is taken over a finite sum and
$$\Big(\sum^{K_\varepsilon}_{k=1}|X_n(k)-X_N(k)|^2\Big)^{1/2}\leq\|X_n-X_N\|_2<\varepsilon$$

---

Comment: Mark's solution is much simpler, but I appreciate the details.

Comment: Thanks! It was nice to see a slightly different method for solving the example but I was mostly trying to understand the particular step I asked about.